# Calculate Break Time Duration with EF or Linq

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

i would like to know how can i calculate break durations and sum total with entity framework or linq. i tried to explain my ms sql table. thanks for your helps.

[image]

```
+---------+-------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| EventId | EventDurations          |  EventName    |  AgentNumber   |
+---------+-------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| 1      |  2016-06-06 09:51:21.570 | Login         | 801            |
| 2      |  2016-06-06 09:51:33.083 | Break         | 801            |
| 3      |  2016-06-06 13:58:14.617 | Login         | 801            |
| 4      |  2016-06-06 15:30:50.600 | Break         | 801            |
| 5      |  2016-06-06 15:46:32.837 | Login         | 801            |
| 6      |  2016-06-06 15:47:16.777 | Break         | 801            |
+--------+--------------------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please also post the data in a form that we can copy and paste into our dev environment. Then we can code and test the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lead in sql query and find that:

```
;with cte as (
select *, datediff(mi,EventDurations, lead(EventDurations,1,EventDurations) over(partition by EventName order by EventDurations)) dur from EventTable
)
select EventName, sum(dur) from cte group by EventName
```

It is still not in EF or linq

Comment: i am using sql server 2008 and there is no lead built-in function

Comment: Can you check this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this? lead/lag without builtin

```
;WITH CTE as 
(
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventName ORDER BY EventDurations), * 
    FROM EventsTable
)
SELECT [Cur_row].*, ISNULL(DATEADD(DAY, -1, [Next_Row].EventDurations), '31-Dec-2099') AS EndDate
FROM   CTE [Cur_row] LEFT JOIN CTE [Next_Row] 
ON [Cur_row].EventId = [Next_Row].EventId AND [Next_Row].RN = [Cur_row].RN + 1
ORDER BY [Cur_row].RN;--if require add eventid
```